# Creating primary key with a static element and an auto-incrementing element without making a composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, primary-key

**The issue**

I have two tables. Both will have auto incrementing `ID` columns which will act as their respective primary key columns.

Table 1 has its `ID` column auto incrementing beginning with 1 and increasing by 1 for each entry. For reference I have used `IDENTITY (1,1)` for this.

I would like table two's `ID` column to behave in the same way but also with a static text/number prefix i.e. M1, M2, M3 or M00001, M00002, M00003 etc.

All of the resources I have found seem to involve the use of a composite primary key; I would like to avoid this.

**Additional info**

From my reading I have come away with the impression that this method may not be the best or right way to differentiate the primary keys of multiple tables within a database, however, I am struggling to find resources/examples on the best or most common methods to do this. I have explored  using composite keys, calculated fields, UUIDs, Hi/Lo algorithm ids and I'm not sure what is the right way to proceed. For context, this is not a big or complicated database.

Even just a link to a good resource on this issue will help me greatly.

Comment: What is the reason you want to create a key with "M1" for example? Explaining what you require this for will help people to advise on the correct solution. The obvious answer is, definitely don't make this any sort of key at all and instead use a computed column.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to differentiate the keys? The usual thinking is that synthetic keys (keys that aren't a part of the data you're storing) generally shouldn't have any meaning/special characteristics beyond being unique for each row and have no nulls.

Comment: Such "smart identifiers" constructed from parts are an anti-pattern. But you can use a unique computed column or unique column set including your identity PK as alternate key. There is no reason to avoid a composite key though. You should probably post a question about how you are stuck doing what you want to do.

Comment: Your questions should be faqs. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Requests for off-site resources are off-topic. Dozens of published edited academic & industrial DB design books are free on the web.

Comment: I would strongly argue to leave the primary key on the `ID INT IDENTITY` column and not make your "alphanumeric" column the PK. The `INT` is smaller, it's a numerical value and thus not prone to spelling error, trailing whitespaces, collation issues and much more. You can have a computed column that turns your `ID` column into the format you need - but don't make that the PK!

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If your identifier column is unique within its table, then adding a static prefix to it does not make it **more** unique. I'll guess that you are attempting to store a value from **either of two tables** in a single column of a related table and then joining to both tables with that same column - expecting just one to "work".

Answer (score 1):

In the second table, instead of modifying the index, you can leave it and add a second column with the calculated value. Below is a complete example (I'm using a tabular variable but it looks the same in a normal table) of such a field in the table.

```
declare @tab as table 
(
    id int primary key identity(1, 1),
    id2 as concat('M', format(id, '00000#')),
    someColumn nvarchar(10)
)

insert into @tab (someColumn) values
(N'test 1'), ('test 2'), (N'test 3');

select * from @tab;
```

The result os the last query is

[image]

As you can see the `id2` is automatically calculated based on the value of the `id` index.

If you want to store the `id2` then you have to modify the table by adding **PERSISTED** like in code below

```
declare @tab as table 
(
    id int primary key identity(1, 1),
    id2 as concat('M', format(id, '00000#')) PERSISTED,
    someColumn nvarchar(10)
)
```

You can find more info about calculated columns [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

**There is no suitable solution.**

But the following query can be used

```
IF Not Exists(Select * From sys.tables t where t.name='ids')
Begin
    Create Table ids(id int)
    Insert into ids values(0)
End
Go
IF Not Exists(Select * From sys.tables t where t.name='tbltextIdentity')
Create Table tbltextIdentity (id  varchar(50) primary key ,someColumn nvarchar(10))
Go
--insert into tbltextIdentity values('M000001','Test1')
UPDATE Ids SET  Id = id +1 OUTPUT concat('M', format(INSERTED.Id, '00000#')), 'Test1' INTO tbltextIdentity 
Go
Select * From tbltextIdentity
```